# Convergence of the sequence of maxima of a converging sequence of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

We are given a sequence of functions $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that converge pointwise to a limiting function $f$. Each $f_n$ has a unique maximum, $x_n$, and $f$ has a unique maximum $x_0$. Now we have to find a sequence of functions $f_n \to f$, but such that $x_n$ does not converge to $x_0$.

I found one adjacent question here ([Convergence of the sequence of maxima of a function sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039405/convergence-of-the-sequence-of-maxima-of-a-function-sequence)), but this one deals with a uniform converging sequence on a compact set. I tried to think of functions on $(0,1)$ but so far no success. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try to think of a function $f_1 \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with two "peaks", one of them being the unique maximum of the function and the other a little bit less tall. For the definition of $f_2, f_3, \dots$ let the taller peak "escape" to infinity, so that the other peak (which did not move) is the unique maximum of the limit $f$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).